# Fontconfig problem only with one program (qt5)

Tags: manjaro, qt, fontconfig

I have very strange problem. One single program (xnviewmp) recently stopped to display any texts in the UI. The graphic part of the UI works.

The OS is Manjaro Linux (Arch) with XFCE.

The program does not seems to be buggy and happened to work for long time. The problem appeared after some installation/update (I don't know exactly).

Starting from the console, I read the following error messages:

```
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 38215135: syntax error
Fontconfig error: Cannot load config file from /etc/fonts/fonts.conf
Fontconfig warning: no <cachedir> elements found. Check configuration.
Fontconfig warning: adding <cachedir>/var/cache/fontconfig</cachedir>
Fontconfig warning: adding <cachedir prefix="xdg">fontconfig</cachedir>
```

The file `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` exists and has the proper permissions. Notice the very strange line number in the first error message.

I tried to delete `/etc/fonts/fonts.cong`, and surprisingly xnviewpm started to work properly. But this, of course can not be a solution.

The UI of the program is based on QT, but all other QT based programs work fine.

The program xnviewmp, was updated today as a part of the regular OS updates, but the problem still persists.

Tried to create new user in order to exclude my local settings, but the problem still persists.

Any ideas how to fix this problem, or at least how to continue the diagnostics?

Comment: Looks interesting for me https://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=36336

Comment: @Bahamut Thanks, this link is what I missed to find. :)